# How can I ensure that the long div stands beside the other small divs, while keeping the layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to create this grid layout, but I can't seem to align the div elements properly.

This is what I intend to do:

[image]

```js
// JavaScript code to show/hide the Back to Top button and handle scroll behavior
var backToTopButton = document.querySelector('.back-to-top');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 200 && window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight < document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
    backToTopButton.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    backToTopButton.classList.remove('show');
  }
});

backToTopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width:360px) {
  body {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
    /* Center the button */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 53px;
    line-height: 95.2%;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 10%;
    ;
  }
  .h1btn {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40%;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  .workbtn {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-left: 34px;
    background-color: #FF6C2E;
    border-radius: 23px;
    height: 176px;
    box-shadow: 4px 7px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
  }
  .aboutbtn {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-left: 34px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 23px;
    height: 176px;
    box-shadow: 4px 7px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
  }
  .socials {
    border-radius: 23px;
    height: 385px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FF6C2E 28.65%, #000 69.27%);
    box-shadow: 4px 7px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 23px;
    margin-left: 70%;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section id="home">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col logo">

        <h1>Bruno<br>Brandão</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <a href="work">
          <div class="col col-6">

            <div class="col-12 workbtn">
              <h1 class="h1btn">WORK</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="col-6 float-right">

        <div class="col col-6 socials">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <a href="work">
        <div class="col col-6 aboutbtn">
          <h1 class="h1btn">ABOUT</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="work">
</section>

<section id="about">
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As I'mstill a beginner at webdev as a whole, I'm not sure of what to do.

I tried to change the width of the columns, and fiddled with the rows.

Comment: The code you posted is missing a closing brace (`}`) to close your media query, and there's at least one missing `</div>` from your HTML before the closing `</section>` tag; not to mention the JavaScript errors (and JavaScript doesn't seem to be relevant to your problem anyway, so it may as well be removed).